# Eclipse IDE C/C++ and OpenCv don't show anything when compiled

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I wanted to try **`OpenCV 2.4.2`** in **`Eclipse Juno`** with the IDE for **`C/C++`**. I followed all the steps to install and I got everything right.

But when I run nothing is shown.

This is the simple code:

```
#include "opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  {
    IplImage* img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
    cvCircle( img, cvPoint( 320, 240 ), 100, cvScalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 5 );
    cvNamedWindow( "OpenCV Window", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );        
    cvShowImage( "OpenCV Window", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow( "OpenCV Window" ); 
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    return 0;
}
```

When it is running only the below appears this on the console:

> `Info: Nothing to build for ........`

Then nothing ..

Comment: @imulsion still nothing, but appears a new message, -- [New Thread 1388.0x5f0] gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000135 at 0x7c9673be --

Comment: Hmm...that means you do have a new thread but there is an error somewhere else in your code. I don't know c to this level. It is C right? If it's c++ you don't need any parameters in the int main() method

Comment: @imulsion it's c++ and with or without the parameters, nothing appears, but i was searching the error and its look like a bug in MinGW...

Comment: Which version of MinGW did u download?

Comment: Another suggestion: Try writing in notepad and compiling without eclipse. That will tell u if the problem is with MinGW or eclipse

Comment: I have same problem :(, did you resolve it?

Comment: Yes!, i resolve it!my problem was that i didnt link the folder bin with  compilation.. there are 2 folder opencv and opencv2//

Comment: @DiegoVera can you explain better? I'm getting mad about this

Answer (score 0):

You can [find extended documentation here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

> Set the OpenCV enviroment variable and add it to the systems path
>
> First set an enviroment variable to make easier our work. This will hold the build directory of our OpenCV library that we use in our projects. Start up a command window and enter:
>
> ```
> setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x86\vc10     (suggested for Visual Studio 2010 - 32 bit Windows)
> setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc10     (suggested for Visual Studio 2010 - 64 bit Windows)
>
> setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x86\vc11     (suggested for Visual Studio 2012 - 32 bit Windows)
> setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc11     (suggested for Visual Studio 2012 - 64 bit Windows)
> ```

Here the directory is where you have your OpenCV binaries (extracted or built). You can have different platform (e.g. x64 instead of x86) or compiler type, so substitute appropriate value. Inside this you should have two folders called lib and bin. The `-m` should be added if you wish to make the settings computer wise, instead of user wise.